About the effect of adding the OFDM pilot tones on the PAPR effect
I have tried to insert the pilots tones in frequency domain for OFDM to be all ones. I mean the pilot subcarriers will carry 1s. The pilot has been inserted in subcarriers of $1:4:N$, where $N$ is the number of subcarriers. I noticed that difference is about 3 dB higher PAPR effect. What is the reason of that difference? Is it normal?

Your pilots are not pseudo-random.
For example, try
THEPILOTS = qammod(randi([0 3], N/4, 1), 4, 'UnitAveragePower', true);
for i = 1 : iter 
    bits = randi([0 3], N, 1);  %generate binary bits 
    x = qammod(bits, 4, 'UnitAveragePower', true);  %Modulated data  without pilots   
    x_pilot = x; x_pilot(1:4:end) = THEPILOTS;

Note the tail of the CDF requires very high numbers of iter.
For the correlation between data and pilots:
N = 64;
x = qammod(randi([0 3], N, 1), 4, 'UnitAveragePower', true);
THEPILOTS = qammod(randi([0 3], N/4, 1), 4, 'UnitAveragePower', true);
x(1:4:end) = 0; %data
%%
y = zeros(size(x));
y(1:4:end) = THEPILOTS; % pilots
%% Data vs pilots
[cxy,lags] = xcorr(x, y, 'normalized');
%% autocorrelation
[cxx,xlags] = xcorr(x, x, 'normalized');
%%
figure;
plot(lags, abs(cxy).^2); hold on;
plot(xlags, abs(cxx).^2); legend('Data vs pilots','Autocorrelation');
xlabel('lags');



You mean the pilots must be pseudo-random vector to avoid that increase of the PAPR ?

@Sajjad the data before ifft must not be correlated to avoid increasing the peak (in  Peak-to-Average Power Ratio, PAPR) after ifft. Your pilots all 1 violate that requirement; and pseudo randomness is one way to achieve it.

Do you the pilot sequences should not be correlated with the data ? How can I know if the generated sequences are correlated or No?

@Sajjad the pilots and data generated that way are independent.

Could you please add into the code  you added (or add the way to prove that) how I can calculate the correlation between the pilots and data? Because I need to confirm that even when generating the pilot as pseudo-random , it's not correlated also.

@Sajjad calculate the cross correlation. For example use xcorr. I added the visualization. The normalized cross correlation values must be much smaller than 1.

Sorry, but when I replaced the THEPILOTS = ones(N/4,1), i get the same normalized cross correlation values of your figure too. . . Could you please add more details?

@Sajjad I see, you are looking for how to generate pilots that do not increase your PAPR. Is it right? So why don't you use THEPILOTS = qammod(randi([0 3], N/4, 1), 4, 'UnitAveragePower', true);? Also sorry for the misleading comments.

Yes I agree with you, but I need also to understand the reason :).

The idea is simple. Your signal is the concatenation of the pilots and the data. The IFFT is therefore the sum of the IFFT of the data and the pilots. If the pilots are pseudo random like the data AND uncorrelated, the PAPR is the same. Your pilots all 1 violate these requirements. The exact increase of the PAPR can be analyzed by writing down the largest order statistic (the max) and the mean of the IFFT. I don't think my answer answers all your questions, please unaccept it as the best so that other members are motivated to add theirs.

Yes, but now when I add the pilots to be all 1, and take the IFFT with the randomly generated data, why the PAPR is increasing in that case. For example, is it because of the proprieties of DFT matrix that contains such specific values in columns corresponding to the pilot data?  I know the process you are talking about, and when replacing this data by that data we get the results, but I don't know what is the explanation of the reason. Thank you for your effort, but I am sorry that I also need to understand the reason itself.

@Sajjad I have already explained the reason:  The IFFT is the sum of the IFFT of the data and the pilots, and the IFFT of your pilots that contain all 1 has a very large peak value.
